# Toric varieties

Tags: tensor-products, toric-geometry

I've started to read about toric varieties and I have a couple of questions about the definition. There is an example that says the following:

"Given a lattice $N$, an isomorphism $N \simeq \mathbb{Z}^n$ induces an isomorphism $$N \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{C}^{*} \simeq (\mathbb{C}^{*})^n$$. The text defines this tensor product as the Torus of $N$.

My doubts are regarding the tensor product, I don't really have an intuitive understanding of what this tensor product means. Could anyone explain this or suggest any reading that could clarify my doubts?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but the isomorphism $N\otimes_Z C^*\cong (C^*)^n$ comes by extending scalars. You can look at Dummit and Foote page 354, where they mention how to extend scalars in a free module.

Comment: $N$ is an abelian group under addition and $\mathbb C^*$ is an abelian group under multiplication, so they are both $\mathbb Z$ module. You can consider the tensor product as free abelian group generated by symbol $n \otimes t$ with relations, for $k \in \mathbb Z$ $kn \otimes t = n \otimes t^k$, and $(n + n') \otimes t = n \otimes t + n' \otimes t, n \otimes (t \cdot t') = n \otimes t + n \otimes t'$ with $n,n' \in N, t,t' \in \mathbb C^*$.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I am reading "Toric Varieties", by Cox, Little and Schenk. Here are my thoughts about " what this tensor product means " in this scenario:

The lattice N is the set of one-parameter subgroups of the torus. In other words, N consists of curves on the torus that are also subgroups. The tensor product identifies points in the torus with specializations of these curves.

For more details I encourage you to read the first pages of the book.